# Use choice_value option in ChoiceType (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony 3.0.4. I wish replace the value to increment by my label.
I referred to the official documentation unsuccessfully.
I also tried [choices_as_values](https://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values) unsuccessfully too :(

This is a piece of my buildForm() function :

```
->add(
    'fieldName',
    ChoiceType::class,
    array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Yes' => true,
            'No' => true,
            'Maybe' => true,
        ),
        'choice_value' => function ($choice) {
            return $choice;
        },
    )
)
```

And I have a return error 500 :

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Where is this notice being triggered? Can you show a stack trace?

Comment: in  vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList.php at line 158

    $givenValues[$i] = (string) call_user_func($this->valueCallback, $givenChoice);

Comment: Hi, I analyzed the returns of my variable choice and it gets back well the values of my option ' choices ' and the value of my field already inserted in BDD (it is a array value) where from why it did not manage to interpret correctly. Thank you for your help, that allowed me to understand better my error. :)